# how to convert data frame into json format in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
dput(head(y,20))
structure(list(DATETIME = structure(c(1369540800, 1369541700, 
1369542600, 1369543500, 1369544400, 1369545300, 1369546200, 1369547100, 
1369548000, 1369548900, 1369549800, 1369550700, 1369551600, 1369552500, 
1369553400, 1369554300, 1369555200, 1369556100, 1369557000, 1369557900
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CPU = c(14.84, 
13.6333333333333, 14.7666666666667, 13.5333333333333, 17.8666666666667, 
15.9333333333333, 14.2333333333333, 13.3, 10.8333333333333, 9.76666666666667, 
8.93333333333333, 9.43333333333333, 10.2, 6.63333333333333, 13, 
14.3, 15.3666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 17.8666666666667, 14.7
)), .Names = c("DATETIME", "CPU"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to convert this data frame to json format as below:

```
library(RJSONIO)
data<-toJSON(y)
cat(data, file="data.json"
```

when I look at the data.json file, I only the see DATETIME HEADER, not the CPU. What am I doing wrong here?

```
[{"DATETIME":[1369540800,1369541700,1369542600,1369543500,1369544400
```

Comment: This works for me on Windows R 3.0.1.

Comment: @Thomas, are you seeing the CPU header info in the json file (I get the cpu data but not the header)

Comment: I tried this with `rjson` and only DATETIME came through. Then I tried it with `RJSONIO` and everything came through: `{
 "DATETIME": [ 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3695e+09, 1.3696e+09, 1.3696e+09, 1.3696e+09, 1.3696e+09, 1.3696e+09, 1.3696e+09, 1.3696e+09, 1.3696e+09, 1.3696e+09 ],
"CPU": [  14.84, 13.633, 14.767, 13.533, 17.867, 15.933, 14.233,   13.3, 10.833, 9.7667, 8.9333, 9.4333,   10.2, 6.6333,     13,   14.3, 15.367, 16.667, 17.867,   14.7 ] }`

Comment: @Thomas, what are the commands you used?